# Fitting data and getting defined number of minima in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have a data set, example below, that has multiple peaks. I want the x value of minima between the peaks. If I need to define how many minimia, that is not a problem (i.e. I am expecting three peaks in my data, so I can tell the code to get two minimia.)

I used `density()` to fit the data, but I am stuck in getting the multiple minima values:

example data:

```
nn <- 1e4
set.seed(1)
betas<-rbeta(nn,3,2)
sims <- c(betas[1:(nn/2)]*2+1,
          betas[(nn/2+1):nn]*2+3,
          betas[(nn/2+2):nn]*3+4)

hist(sims)
```

I should have a minima value between `x` 3 and 3.5, and `x` 5 and 5.5. I can count the ends as minima, but not a priority for my problem.

[image]

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fitting with `density()`

I used `mSTEM` package for the [`which.peaks()` function](https://rdrr.io/cran/mSTEM/man/which.peaks.html) that worked.